# Check that Coroutine Job was cancelled?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am pretty much newbie with *coroutines*, I have an existing code and I am trying to understand the following behaviour:

```
Log.d(TAG,"Starting example function")

val dispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
Log.d(TAG, "dispatcher $dispatcher isActive: ${dispatcher.isActive}")

try {
    val res = withContext(dispatcher) {

        Log.d(TAG, "withContext(Dispatchers.IO) running")
        Log.d(TAG, "inside dispatcher $dispatcher isActive: ${dispatcher.isActive}")
        ...
    }
} catch (exception: Exception) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Exception: ", exception)
    exception.printStackTrace()
}
```

The code above is being invoked in 2 places, one is from UI:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
```

and the other is from Service via AIDL:

```
var scope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + SupervisorJob()) // in scope of Service object

if (!scope.isActive)
    scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + SupervisorJob())

runBlocking(scope.coroutineContext) {
```

In some cases, it is running ok, with log being - **why is *isActive* always false there?**

```
Starting example function
dispatcher Dispatchers.IO isActive: false
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) running
inside dispatcher Dispatchers.IO isActive: false
```

But in some other cases, this results into exception:

```
Starting example function
dispatcher Dispatchers.IO isActive: false
exception: kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled
kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled; job=SupervisorJobImpl{Cancelling}@8236053
```

Apparently, *dispatcher.isActive* is not enough, **how can I check this *Job was cancelled* state and how to handle it?**

Comment: Can you please provide the whole body of the example function and how exactly do you use it?

Comment: Main issue here was the `dispatcher.isActive` instead of `scope.isActive` - as pointed out by the answer. It started to make sense and the source of issue in the code also came out.

Comment: Yes, but i was wondering why does `dispatcher.isActive` return `false`. Does scope's `isActive` return `true` where `dispatcher.isActive` returns `false`? I tried your code and these two seems to be effectively the same and referring to the `Job.isActive` of the current coroutine's `CoroutineContext`.

Comment: Yes, when I have replaced `${dispatcher.isActive}` with `$isActive` (from CoroutineScope), value changed from `false` to `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not check `isActive` of the dispatcher, but of the current coroutine itself:

```kotlin
Log.d(TAG, "inside dispatcher $dispatcher isActive: $isActive")
```

Please see [Cancellation and timeouts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#making-computation-code-cancellable). This article never suggests to check `isActive` of a dispatcher, only of a current coroutine.